# Автоматический chmod на все загружаемое на FTP

Tags: права, ftp, centos

Добрый день

подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, чтобы на все файлы, загружаемые через определенный FTP аккаунт, автоматически устанавливались нужные мне права доступа или владелец и группа?

Comment: Какой FTP-сервер?

Comment: ProFTPD

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде такого?

```
<Directory /*>
UserOwner   myuser
GroupOwner   mygroup
Umask 022 022
AllowOverwrite on
</Directory>
```

Comment: Добавил это в proftpd.conf, но файлы все равно загружаются с правами 644 (я поставил umask 222) :(